# Saving photo to Android storage not working?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save an image to the phone storage on Android (some phones do not have SDCard so need to save to internal).

The method I am using is;

```
private static void savedtosdcard() {

act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                    try {
                        Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                        m.invoke(null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                String imageName = "Image_Save.png";
                File src = new File(act.getFilesDir(), imageName);
                if (!src.exists()) {
                    //Toast.makeText(me, "No file to share.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }


                Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                String ts = tsLong.toString();


                File dst = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ts + imageName);
                try {
                    CommonUtils.copy(src, dst);

                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    File f = new File(dst.getAbsolutePath());
                    //Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(act, act.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", (f));

                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    act.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                    Toast.makeText(act, "Photo saved to gallery successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The game is not generating any error messages when saving, however there is no image output being saved to the device.
The first time I tried, I had 2 new directories created in photos

"camtest" & "directoryName" both have blank files in them.

I am testing on a device with Android 6, but have other devices much newer with same issue.

Comment: check out scoped storage permission.

Comment: `trying to save an image to the phone storage` ? No. You are trying to copy a file that is already on your device.

Comment: `//Toast.makeText(me, "No file to share.",` ?? File not found!  ?

Comment: `CommonUtils.copy(src, dst);` Where is the return value? Or does it throw? `if ( !CommonUtils.copy(src, dst)) return;`

Comment: You have no Toast() in that catch block. Inform the user!

Comment: `need to save to internal)` That is how you name it. But you use .get`External`StorageDirectory().